# selectedIndex not working with multiple mat-tab-group

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-tab

I have multiple mat-tab-group into a single HTML page like :

```html
    <mat-card class="card-app-content">
        <mat-tab-group [(selectedIndex)]="selectedIndex">
            ...
        </mat-tab-group
    </mat-card>

    <mat-card class="card-app-content">
        <mat-tab-group [(selectedIndex)]="selectedIndexMedia">
            ...
        </mat-tab-group
    </mat-card>

    <mat-card class="card-app-content">
        <mat-tab-group [(selectedIndex)]="selectedIndexHistory">
             ...
        </mat-tab-group
    </mat-card>
```

My .ts contains :

```js
    selectedIndex           : number = 0;
    selectedIndexMedia      : number = 0;
    selectedIndexHistory    : number = 0;
```

In the first mat-tab-group, the index 0 is well selected (the first mat-tab is underline) but for the two others, no mat-tab are underline, likes no one of are selected :/

Here is a stackblitz reproducing the problem : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-oykb2e?file=app/tab-group-dynamic-example.html

For example,
Working :

[image: working]

Not working :

[image: Not working]

Comment: Could you please provide a [mcve] of the problem you're facing? The code you've provided is not substantial enough to reproduce your problem.

Comment: I updated the topic with a stackblitz :)

Answer (score 0):

I Resolved it by checking `*ngIf="selectedIndex==1"` on the second tab.

check out [this demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-oykb2e-jy7zrr?file=app%2Ftab-group-dynamic-example.html).